# Heroku Removing Gemfile.lock because it was generated on Windows

Tags: heroku

Does anyone have any idea about this one? Trying to deploy to heroku. I am able to do a successful launch to heroku but I suspect this warning is probably the reason I get the sorry something went wrong message. Any input on this would be appreciated. By the way I am thinking this is a Windows issue. To be honest this is my first crack at this and it's been interesting so far but if this is the nonsense I am going to deal with trying to develop on Windows I might as well get cracking on setting up a linux machine. I know there will be complications as well but who knows. I have installed and used it before but never for development. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Ruby 2.0.0
Rails 4.0.0
Windows 7 64

WARNINGS:
Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.

Just for reference here is the whole push to heroku:

```
c:\dev\project2>git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/vern/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.5)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.8.2)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using activesupport (4.0.0)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.0)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Using activemodel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.1)
       Using activerecord (4.0.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using mysql2 (0.3.14)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.10.1)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Using rails (4.0.0)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using sass (3.2.12)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
       Using sdoc (0.3.20)
       Using turbolinks (1.3.1)
       Using uglifier (2.3.1)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (9.55s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (2.58s)
       Cleaning assets
```

----->

```
WARNINGS:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 21.1MB
-----> Launching... done, v12
       http://fast-lake-6950.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:fast-lake-6950.git
   c81423c..01c6a2d  master -> master
```

Answer (score 9):

your `Gemfile.lock` file likely contains

```
PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32
```

You need to remove

```
  x86-mingw32
```

for it to play nicely with heroku. There may be lines in your `Gemfile.lock` that conflict with removing that, e.g. you might have installed a separate version of the `mysql2` gem for windows.

```
mysql2 (0.3.11-x86-mingw32)
mysql2 (0.3.14)
```

you will likely need to remove the line that references the windows-only version of the gem. And for that to work, you may need to remove the line in your `Gemfile` that causes bundler to install that gem.