# Easiest way to deploy a Rails app (windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, heroku

I have a rails app that needs to be put online (anywhere) - I am using a windows machine, I tried to deploy it using Heroku but that was a huge pain. The app only needs to go online so I can show it to someone - It only needs to be up about a week, so setting up a Virtual Linux system on my windows laptop is not a preference for me.

Comment: "but that was a huge pain" What exactly went wrong? Heroku is by far and away the easiest way to deploy Rails apps.

Comment: I get the error 'Removing Gemfile.lock because it was generated on Windows.' - After searching I found I had to delete ' PLATFORMS x86-mingw32' - I did that but when I do bundle install, it just re-adds it again. –  Mark Shakespeare 27 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to follow a specific procedure to get Gemfile.lock to work for Heroku. This answer has some basic instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21488679/693349

However, you'd probably do better to read the full Heroku docs about "Deploying a Ruby Project Generated on Windows": https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Digital Ocean?

https://www.digitalocean.com/features/one-click-apps/ruby-on-rails/

Normally deployment at heroku works like charm, what was the problem?

Comment: I get the error 'Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.' - After searching I found I had to delete '
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32'    - I did that but when I do bundle install, it just re-adds it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Capistrano gem](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/). Is an especific gem to deploy Ruby on Rails projects and it works perfect!

You have a good tutorial [here](http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/04/04/deploying-rails-apps-part-5-configuring-capistrano/) to configure Capistrano.

Comment: The guys is saying he found Heroku confusing, and you are suggesting he uses Capistrano? Seriously?