# Heroku library issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I had a Ruby on Rails project dropped on me. I don't know Ruby at all... but code changes aren't needed. The problem is libraries. I got an error that Heroku helpfully directed me to [Heroku Removing Gemfile.lock because it was generated on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297205/heroku-removing-gemfile-lock-because-it-was-generated-on-windows). This wasn't as much help as I hoped. The Gemfile didn't contain any references to the libraries mentioned in the answer. I started trying to work out what might have been Windows related. However, I added nothing to the file, just updated version numbers. The Gemfile I was using came straight from the project on Heroku. I don't see how anything Windows related could have been added. Anyway, I really don't know what I'm looking for. Here's the Gemfile Heroku isn't liking:

```
ruby '3.2.2'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'bundler', '>= 2.4.10'
gem 'rails', '7.0.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
gem 'skylight', '~> 5.3.4'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0.0'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'chartjs-ror', '~> 3.7.0' # git: 'git://github.com/paulstefanort/chartjs-ror.git', ref: '3b6184ac39'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'local_time'
gem 'devise'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 4.2.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.11.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 4.2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
gem 'spring-commands-rspec', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'rspec-rails', group: [:development, :test]
group :development do
  gem 'sexp_processor'
  gem 'flog'
  gem 'better_errors'
end
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'rspec-sidekiq'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
gem 'dotenv-deployment', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'mail'
gem 'zbase32', github: 'paulstefanort/zbase32-ruby'
gem 'lol_dba', group: :development
gem 'chosen-rails'
#gem 'chosen-sass-bootstrap-rails', github: 'caarlos0-graveyard/chosen-sass-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'mandrill-rails'
gem 'griddler', '1.5.2'
gem 'griddler-sendgrid', '1.2.0'
gem 'gcm'
gem 'pusher'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-limit_fetch'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
gem 'sinatra', require: false
#gem 'quarry', github: 'paulstefanort/quarry'
gem 'keen'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 2.7.1', github: 'reactjs/react-rails'
gem 'airbrake'
#gem 'rbtrace'
gem 'countries'
#gem 'rmagick', '5.2.0'
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-react-bootstrap'
end
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm looking for and what I might change?

Answer (score 1):

When you get a warning like this on Heroku

```
Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
```

then the problem is likely not a gem that is only available on Windows and not available for any other platform. But a gem that has multiple platform specific versions, and only the Windows version was installed.

For example, there is the [`nokogiri`](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions) gem, which is a transitive dependency of Ruby on Rails' [`actiontext`](https://rubygems.org/gems/actiontext) library. Each version of this gem comes in different versions natively build for specific platforms, like `x86-mingw32`, `x86-linux`, `java`, and others.

To allow Bundler to load the correct version on different platforms, you have to tell bundler on what platforms you want to use your app and what gem versions to keep available when generating the `Gemfile.lock`.

You can check what platforms are configured currently with `bundle platform` that might return something like this:

```
PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32
```

This means Bundler will only install the `ruby` version of a gem (which is basically the default for most gems) and a `x86-mingw32` version when there are multiple versions for different platforms available.

But Heroku is running their platform on Linux. Therefore, you have to tell Bundler to add `x86_64-linux` platform support too. Once that is done, run `bundle install` again, commit the changes and push those changes to Heroku:

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby    # only if `ruby` is not returned by `bundle platform`
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
bundle install

# git commit and push to Heroku
```

When you do not use Windows anymore for future development of the application, then I suggest removing it explicitly with

```
bundle lock --remove-platform x86-mingw32
```

You might need to change `x86-mingw32` to whatever Windows specific platform string was returned by the `bundle platform` command.

When you develop on Apple Silicon, you might want to add `arm64-darwin`, for a Mac with an Intel CPU `x86_64-darwin` too.