# Ruby active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

Not long ago, I asked this question: [Heroku library issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76784795/heroku-library-issues/76785254#76785254)

Given the answers I got, I created an Ubuntu Linux VM on my computer. In retrospect, it might have been easier to grab an old laptop of mine, but it's water under the bridge. The VM works fine. The answers were correct; I got much further trying to push out to Heroku. After a handful of missteps, and numerous updates until I got `bundle install` to operate cleanly. Then I discovered the `rake` step. That was failing with this error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Serializer`

After looking over numerous Stack Overflow questions and answers as well as a few articles about Serializers in Ruby, I realized that it was coming down to one line in my gemfile:

`gem 'active_model_serializers'`

One answer to my problem was to amend the line as follows:

`gem 'active_model_serializers', github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers"`

The other half of that answer was to edit the Ruby files and change the name to `ActiveModelSerializers` from `ActiveModel::Serializer`. The only thing about that is it changes the above error to complain about the new name. Apparently the datatype `ActiveModel::Serializer` isn't know when the code is being compiled. This led to another answer explain that you could explicitly include type somehow, or modify the gemfile to add `require: true`. I've even tried to be explicit about the revision. The settings I've tried in the gemfile just don't seem to work for me. Here are the variations I've tried:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'active_model_serializers', require: true
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~>0.10.13'
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers"
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers", require: true
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~>0.10.13', github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers", require: true
```

If I can get a `builder install` command to work on my local machine with the libraries I have , it fails when it hits Heroku. Some of their instructions are to make sure the rake runs on my local machine. If I get that to work, then when I upload to Heroku, I get complaints about version differences, and it won't get to the rake step.

It's a huge Ruby project a client doesn't want to recreate, just get built again because certain features were deprecated from the old system and those programmers are gone. And my knowledge of Ruby was confined to knowing its existence weeks ago.

Comment: You should include the ruby version and rails version in your question.

Comment: According to the rails-api/active_model_serializers readme (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) -- the gem is undergoing substantial redevelopment. Also note it hasn't really been updated in 6 years. Might look for ways to remove it from your implementation.

Comment: 3.2.2. But thanks for the comment, dbugger, but sadly it causes more despair than hope.

Comment: That's the ruby version -- add it to the QUESTION along with the RAILS version. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: Expecting a 6 year old gem to work with the most recent version of Ruby is a fools errand. The client has asked for a likely impossible task.

Comment: I don't know enough about Ruby & Rails to know what kind of an errand it is, but a fellow programmer and I took your comment to heart and it looks like I'm learning Ruby a bit. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your best bet might be to examine all the versions of everything in production, and tighten up your software and dependency specifications so that it builds everything exactly like prod. You can add a little leeway if you have solid integration tests. Then at least you will have a buildable application, and you can make small feature/fix adjustments from there.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's advice. The Ruby project interfaced to hardware that the manufacturer is excessively stingy on providing technical details enough for me to repair this thing, or even re-write it in something else. The whole thing has been abandoned. But, boy do I have a bad taste in my mouth regarding Ruby.